# Vent now blows on thermostat

Tags: thermostat, venting

A long story how this got this way but there's a house with two furnaces and two thermostats. One of the furnaces feeds a long hallway with the return vent at one end and four feeder vents evenly spaced in the ceiling from one end to the other. There are no windows at the return vent end so it gets cold back there while the other end seems fine cause there are windows.

One issue is that the thermostat for this side is directly below the second vent from the back of the house where the return vent is. Placing a thermometer there registers three or four degrees warmer than the back of the house by the return vent.

I'm not sure if it would be best to just remove the vent above the thermostat or maybe close this one down along with the next one closest to the return. I can't move the thermostat but to the wall on the other side of the hall. I don't want the front of the house vents pumping more heat just to warm up the back of the house and then the front of the house gets too hot.

I'm just perplexed at the moment and looking for suggestions.

Comment: You could try a plastic cover they reduce the air movement on the thermostat. not sure if that will work in this case but might be worth a try.

Comment: You could consider a wireless thermostat. This would allow you to place the temperature sensing portion of the thermostat any where you want .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, play with closing the flaps of however many it takes. It really depends on who, how & when the ducts were installed, balance is the aim but the only thing that does get balanced (maybe) is what's in use at the time the system goes active.

In my house, I have to keep 2 vents closed year round & then heating & cooling seasons have to have additional & different vents opened or closed for fairly uniform temperatures.

If things level out for you with just the thermostat vent shut, then leave it that way or you can possibly go to a new vent whose fins blow the air to either side & never at the thermostat. Also, you might be able to move the thermostat out of the hallway altogether.

Comment: I'm going to try and shut one or two vents down this weekend and see what happens.

Comment: Don't worry, nothing will blow up. Just slap them shut & you'll know in an hour or so if things are better, worse or no different to then shut more or open a shut one & shut another open one.

Comment: It's not a question of fear. I'm looking for ideas wrt air flow while keeping a balanced system as best as can be done with this layout.

Comment: Yeah right! I know you think you're going to turn off the Sun or an Angel won't get it's wings. I'm just kidding of course. It just sounded that way when you said you're going to wait until the weekend & see what happens.

Comment: Not my house. Helping someone else.

Comment: Oh, well then maybe... No, that explains it perfectly. It should work out fine, the trying & waiting is the real pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy magnetic vent covers that have a curved plastic top. They can redirect the air away from the thermostat without having to close the vent.